# CREATE VIEW and RETRIEVE data in Microservices

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, microservices, create-view

I have two microservices A & B using two different tables TA & TB via mysql db. The tables are related via a PK FK relationship. I am required to call all the details of from TB along with TA using the B.

I am using JpaRepo, I tried doing it using @Query, NamedNativeQueries, and CREATE VIEW. Kindly give an example on how I can perform this action of CREATE VIEW to join TA & TB and get the data from the VIEW using a method !.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a small suggestion on your architecture: Your microservices should never share a common database schema, and certainly not share any tables. Otherwise you will have such a strong dependency between the two services, that sweeps off all advantages of microservices. If service A needs data from service B, use e.g. REST communication.

Comment: @dunni Thank you for that tip. I shall keep it in mind while writing new Micro-Services.